# ending a passbook program - HTTP response to incoming passbook requests?

Tags: passbook

We attempted a passbook program but it never made it out of beta, but there are a few passes out there that keep phoning home (and throwing errors because the passes are out of sync with existing data). My plan is to 404 any incoming requests, but I'm not sure if that is the best way to handle existing passes. Any other ideas or is 404 the right solution?

Comment: If possible then send a new pass without a webServiceURL.  Else better to send a 302, not modified since 4xx or 5xx responses will cause the device to retry.

Comment: @PassKit thanks, I've dropped this into production and will monitor for a couple days. Will let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few of options:

- Return an updated pass without that has a blank web service url
- Return an appropriate error
- Remove the DNS entry of the subdomain

### Update the web service url

Any of the fields in the pass can be updated including the web service url. Removing the url will prevent further requests for updates. This s potentially the most effective, but would require a bit of development to return the updated pass and would need to be maintained until all passes have been "disabled."

### Return an appropriate error code

It may be easier to simply return an error code. This could be done through the web server configuration preventing the requests from being processed by your application (and presumably stop the errors in the application). This would allow you to remove the code altogether from your application.

The *[Passbook Web Service Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html)* indicates that Passbook will eventually give up when receiving persistent errors.

> If a request fails—for example, due to a network connectivity issue—Passbook tries again several times after waiting a period of time. Each time it tries again, it waits longer. If the request continues to fail, it eventually gives up.

The documentation also indicates that standard HTTP status codes should be used in the response from the call to *Getting the Latest Version of a Pass* (and others).

> **Response**
>
> - If request is authorized, return HTTP status 200 with a payload of the pass data.
> - If the request is not authorized, return HTTP status 401.
> - Otherwise, return the appropriate standard HTTP status.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Support standard HTTP caching on this endpoint: check for the If-Modified-Since header and return HTTP status code 304 if the pass has not changed.

It sounds like the ending of the passbook program is permanent in which case **410 Gone** would be an appropriate error code. (From [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)).

> **410 Gone**
>
> The requested resource is no longer available at the server and no forwarding address is known. This condition is expected to be considered permanent. Clients with link editing capabilities SHOULD delete references to the Request-URI after user approval. If the server does not know, or has no facility to determine, whether or not the condition is permanent, the status code 404 (Not Found) SHOULD be used instead. This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise.
>
> The 410 response is primarily intended to assist the task of web maintenance by notifying the recipient that the resource is intentionally unavailable and that the server owners desire that remote links to that resource be removed. Such an event is common for limited-time, promotional services and for resources belonging to individuals no longer working at the server's site. It is not necessary to mark all permanently unavailable resources as "gone" or to keep the mark for any length of time -- that is left to the discretion of the server owner.

### Remove subdomain DNS

If your web service url was set up on a separate subdomain (e.g. passbook.example.com) you can simply remove the DNS entry for the subdomain. The requests will never reach the server and Passbook will eventually give up.